# Adding units to numeric labels in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript, expression, units

How do I add the distance units to labels in ArcMap?

I have the area calculated and would like the label to be displayed as (XXX sq ft).

I was able to write a VBScript of `"(" & [AREA] &" )"` but am not sure how to include the "sqft" inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

The parentheses in your label `"("` and `")"` are text values that are added to your `[AREA]` value, so you can add any other text you want with it.

```vbs
"(" & [AREA] & " sqft)"
```

will produce something like `(1000 sqft)` as your label.